# Example of " remove unused imports" can have bad side effects in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, import

I'm looking for an example of how removing unused imports can lead to breaking otherwise valid programs. My question was inspired looking at this issue:  https://github.com/psf/black/issues/86

Could someone please point me to an example?

Answer (score 8):

When you import a module in Python, you execute all the code in that file (and all of its imports).

***By convention only*** this code is side-effectless and usually just provides classes and such, but there's no real reason this has to be true. A poorly written module could perform necessary steps to function correctly as part of the code triggered during import.

For example it's entirely possible to have code like:

```py
# my_db/init.py
    from my_db.core import MyDB

    MyDB.do_very_important_setup()


# my_db/other.py
    import my_db.init
    from my_db.core import MyDB

    MyDB.do_some_work_assuming_setup_has_occurred()
```

Is this horrible? *Yes*. Should you do it? *No*.

Can you guarantee nobody else has?

Answer (score 2):

When a module first gets imported, all the code within that module is run. Convention and good practice dictates that the module *shouldn't* make any changes to the rest of the environment, but this isn't always the case (for example, a module could change a couple of variables in `sys` for the entire program, when it's first imported).

It is possible that someone could import such a module purely for its side effects, and then never explicitly refer to it in the rest of their code. A linting/formatting tool like `black` would then detect it as unused, and remove it, and suddenly the side-effects it was having are no longer in effect, and the program breaks as a result.

I can't come up with any specific examples at this time, but I know I've seen at least one before, and I was personally working on such a module until I realized it was a poor idea and stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have following structure:

```
- root
   |--folder1
         |-- __init__.py
         |-- server.py
   |--main.py
```

And following content:

```
# main.py
import folder1 as f
print("I am doing stuff but don't need f")


# __init__.py
from folder1 import server


#  server.py
# Start a server, or do something else you need
```

When you remove the `folder1` import in `main.py` it would stop doing the thins in `__init__.py` and `server.py`. I would definetly consider that as bad code, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers your question, but if you remove the unused import, the first 2 icons are not displayed anymore.

https://github.com/theonlycodingbear/unused-imports-problem.git